# How to create a vb script that converts individual tabs excel to csv files where fields contain semicolons

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro that splits an excel files tabs into individual csv files. The issue I am facing is that some fields contain semicolons and during the csv conversion the field is split into the other column.

I was wondering if there was a way to keep the macro from recognizing semicolons as delimiters?

Thank you

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()

Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long

CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
' Store current details for the workbook

    SaveToDirectory = "C:\Users\Antonio Robles\Dropbox\Fit_Bit_Samples\Logistics\Logistics\Sample Files\csv_files\"

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlCSV
    Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
'  about overwriting the original file.

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue I am facing is that some fields contain semicolons and
>   during the csv conversion the field is split into the other column.

I am getting following sample  output from your program. It is not splitting to new columns on semicolons.

```
good morning : hello    aa
we want it; right       bb
let us go , together    cc
```

Please recheck at your end. It was not possible in comments Hence answered it.

Comment: Really sorry not sure what happened on my end I retried the script and it worked. Not sure why it split, the last time.

Answer (score 0):

Alright realized the issue. I used this macro on my windows os in excel. Then I accessed the same file using my linux os(ubuntu) in dropbox,  via libre office calc csv version, some how accessing it through libre it automatically made some changes and I saved it. So lesson is libre may modify changes from an excel/csv file.